# R: How to access a variable which name has been created on the fly (with paste)

Tags: r

I'm wondering how to create a variable name (of a variable that already exist) using paste and then access this variable.

Example:

```
var<-c("A","B","C")

for (i in 1:3){
     paste0("var")[i] 
}
```

*Note: Assume, that I need to use `paste0` to create the variable name (I'm dealing with data.frames and use `paste0` to create the variables for the different columns)*

Thanks!

EDIT:

Alright, here's the bigger picture:
I have two data frames: `smallDF` and `bigDF`. I want to copy data from bigDF to smallDF. Matching is done with the `user_name`.

```
user <- c("userA","userB","userC")
variables<-c("user_age","user_city","user_street")

for (t in 1:length(variables)){

  for (j in 1:length(user)){

    x<-paste0("bigDF$",variables[t])
    y<-paste0("smallDF$",variables[t])

    tmp<-unique(x[which(bigDF$user_name==user[j])])[1] # unique will only yield one entry
    replace<-c(as.character(rep(tmp,length(y[which(smallDF$user_name==user[j])]))))
    y[which(smallDF$user_name==user[j])]<-replace

  }
}
```

The code above does not work. However, when I avoid the first for-loop and replace x and y with the respective variable names (bigDF$user_age etc) everything works. That's why I thought there must be a simple way of creating those variable names on the fly with the outer for-loop.
Thanks everybody!

Comment: You most likely don't need this. Show your full task and better possibilities can be demonstrated.

Comment: I agree with @Roland the question isn't entirely clear. Give us an idea of what you want to achieve with this and we can probably provide better, more useful assistance.

Comment: `paste0` takes multiple arguments, so maybe you are looking for `paste0("var", var[i])` to create names `varA`, `varB` and `varC`? Then, if these are the column names in a data.frame, then you can access them one-by-one by doing `df[[paste0("var", var[i])]]`. Or you can access all three columns by doing `df[paste0("var", var)]`.

Comment: I don't really understand your code, it is very convoluted (and not reproducible because we lack the data.frames). However, from your problem description it seems you simply want to merge two data.frames. So maybe `?merge` will help you?

Comment: it's more a question of how to create a name that is treated as a variable. accessing this variable using `[..]` is no problem. How to create `x` as a placeholder when you want to do `x[...]`

Comment: Could you please extract a small part of `smallDF` and `bigDF` and add to you question using `dput`? Something like `dput(smallDF[1:5,])`. It would make it a lot easier to answer you question.

Comment: Much easier and more reliable to create a `list` and just name the elements.

Comment: @SPi you really *really* need to use the `merge` command and forget this nonsense with `for` loops and `paste0`. I say this to help. Please add the output from `dput( head( small_df ) )` and `dput( head( big_df ) )` and let us help you the **`R`** ight way. :-)

Comment: I second the comments above. I bet this can all be done in a single call to `merge()`.

Comment: thanks everybody! Appreciate your help! I did a workaround using `merge()`

Answer (score 3):

First look at the help `?"[["` then possibly at `fortune(312)`.  The problem is that somewhere along the line you learned about the magical `$` shortcut without properly learning about what it is a shortcut for and feel that you need to use the shortcut in cases where it is the longest distance between 2 points (kind of like using a shortcut between New York City and Boston when trying to get from London to Paris).

If you use code like `bigDF[[ variables[t] ]]` instead of trying to use `$` then that will access the column of `bigDF` with the name currently in `variables[t]`.

Learn to use `[[` and other subsetting properly (only use `$` where appropriate) and your whole process will be greatly simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
    dat <- eval(parse(text="paste0"))
```

in *dat* you have the output.

Comment: If you think you need `eval(parse())` you should take a step back and reconsider your whole approach.

Comment: ...same goes for `get` and `mget` to be honest.

Comment: @Roland I answered the question. I don't think care about possible solutions. That's a new question.

Comment: @Laszlo-AndrasZsurzsa the point is that your proposed solution is not a robust approach in more general problems, so it's not recommended in general.

Comment: It's hard to answer if someone is changing the problem every hour. Error corrected by the way.